# XSLT transform of XML files in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: xml, xslt, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a collection of XML files and resw files that are translated to different languages. In an Azure DevOps release pipeline I would like to use an xsl file to transform these XML files to another XML format (a translation memory, txm). I know how to write the xsl to align the languages in the XML files.

What is the best way to add this XML file transform to the pipeline?
I have been looking at the `File transform` task, but it is very confusing. I do not see how I can use this task for XML transformation. It seems like I could specify something like  `-transform **\*.xsl -xml **\*.xml` in  `Transformation rule`, but I have nowhere to specify the output.

Is this even the right task for XML transformation with xslt? If not, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The File transform does not seem to have the task of transforming XML files with Xslt.

To transform XML files with xslt it is better to use a PowerShell task, for example:

```
          $Xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
          $Xslt.Load($PathToXsltFile)
          $Xslt.Transform($PathOfXMLInputFile, $PathOfOutputFile)
```